# 3d rectangle switches visible side in negative z?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I'm playing with vertexes and normals using the following code:

```
    float col = 0;
    float row = 0;
    float level = 1;

private Vector3 tmp(float x, float y, float z) {
        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    meshPartBuilder.rect(tmp(col, 0, row +1),

            tmp(col, level, row +1),

            tmp(col, level, row),

            tmp(col, 0, row), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
```

This gives me the expected result:

[image]

Now i got into negative z area:

```
    meshPartBuilder.rect(tmp(col, 0, row - 1),

            tmp(col, level, row - 1),

            tmp(col, level, row),

            tmp(col, 0, row), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
```

[image]

Now suddenly the rectangle is invisible. For unknown reasons it is visible from the other side, it seems the "visible" side has switched when going to negative z.

[image]

How can i make the rectangle visible when going into negative z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called backface culling. The order of the vertices (counter clock-wise) are used to determine which side of the face is front and which side is the backside. The back sides are by default not rendered (culled) so the GPU doesn't have to render things which wont be visible anyway.

The `MeshPartBuilder#rect` method allows you to specify the corners when you look at the front side of the rectangle. Corner00 is the lower left corner, corner10 is the lower right corner, corner11 is the upper right corner and corner01 is the upper left corner.

The perspective projection uses by default the right-handed system. Meaning that the Z axis point towards the viewer. So you practically have to swap the horizontal corners to make it visible from the other side. Alternatively you could swap the vertical corners if you prefer that.

Comment: Cheers for the answer @Xoppa, i understand backface culling and the way rect works. Because the face I'm rendering is the left side i used corners 001,011,010,000 for rect function ( http://www.scratchapixel.com/old/assets/Uploads/Interpolation/trilinearfig.png ). I appreciate your solution for swapping corners, but I'm having trouble understanding why. Can you please explain this a bit more? I ask this because otherwise i have to have implement 2 ways to render a rect, one for positive z and one for when a rect sits in negative z.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? You do need to specify the corners in the correct order. If that means that you have to implement it in 2 ways, then that's how it is.

Comment: after a fresh look at the subject this morning i start to understand it better, i was confused about the vertex winding on the left pane. The way the vertex winds should always be counter clockwise, otherwise the triangle will flip.